# How to get iTunes to play songs in order of appearance when shuffle is off?

Tags: itunes

I’m DJing a swing dance and as I’m watching the dance floor, I’m rearranging the songs to take out the fast ones. As I was sitting there watching I expected the next song in order to play (songs were sorted by the first column, i.e. the sequential numbers) but it went from song 4 down to song 25. I think song 25 was one of the fast ones I had thrown down at the bottom.

I double checked that shuffle was off and indeed it was off. I’m using my wife’s laptop and I know that my laptop does not do this. I DJ’ed swing dances for years and never saw this happen. I may have encountered it long ago and fixed it, but it’s been a long time since I DJ’ed (maybe 2 or 3 years).

So what settings do I need to check?

Comment: Can you pls specify the macOS version on the laptop?

Comment: I don’t have her computer in front of me now, but I’d be willing to bet it’s Sierra.